# Laravel Validate file extension?

Tags: laravel, file, validation, mime-types

I have the following FormRequest that validates `Files`, specifically audio files:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'bail|required|file|mimes:mpeg,mp3,mp2,aiff,wav,wave,flac,m4a,caf,ogg,aac,amr,wma|max:500000000'
    ];
}
```

However, for some reason, when I upload any type of audio file, I get a `422` stating the file type is invalid... What is the cause of this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my `ajax` using `axios`:

```
const f = new FormData()
f.append('file', file)
const config = {
headers: {
'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
}
}
return axios.post('myendpoint', f, config).then((response) => {
// handle
}).catch((thrown) => {
if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
return console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
}
return console.log(thrown)
})
```

Comment: see the file's mime type using `dd($request->file);` because most of the time mp3 file has the `mpga` mime type, so check it in your `endpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your form:

`enctype=“multipart/form-data"`

EDIT:
In order to properly append your uploaded file to FormData, you need to use `onchange` event on the:

**input**

`<input type=“file” onchange=“getFile”>`

**handler**

```
function getFile(event) {
   file = event.target.files
}
```

Read through [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problems-with-uploading-file-using-vuejs-2-and-laravel-54?page=1) for more information.

Comment: it's not a form, its an ajax request using `axios` with `formData.append()` , and `'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'` ... Is there any other configs i should add?

Comment: Please provide your ajax code and how you append the file to your form (edit your question). It would give people more insight.